# FirebaseAuth requires CocoaPods version 1.12.0 which is not satisfied by your current version 1.11.3

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

I can't install the new project in IOS simulator. When I run

> pod install

I get "FirebaseAuth requires CocoaPods version 1.12.0 which is not satisfied by your current version 1.11.3" message.
I have executed the below command to update pods but after this when I enter pod install it gives me the error.

> sudo gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- brew upgrade cocoapods worked for me!
- For M1 arch -arm64 brew upgrade cocoapods

Answer (score 1):

Run this command `brew cleanup -d -v` .

Then run this command `brew install cocoapods`

Comment: exected them and then after that when I run pod install ended up with same error.

Comment: Check whether CocoaPods has updated to version 1.12.0 or higher using  `pod --version` command

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. brew upgrade cocoapods worked and it changed the pod version. 
 Before that multiple I executed multiple command, even your ones but pod --version was returing older version.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Worked for me

Comment: Tried it multiple times. Didn't work with me.